# Per-route on-time performance for VIA rail

Tags: trains, canada, delays, via-rail

Is there anywhere to find per-route on-time performance for VIA Rail, similar to [Amtrak's reports](http://www.amtrak.com/historical-on-time-performance)?

All I found is a [2011 statistic for select routes](http://www.viarail.ca/2011annualreport/docs/dl.php?file=VIA-Rail-Annual-Report-2011.pdf) and overall statistics for 2008-2013 in the [2013 report](http://www.viarail.ca/sites/all/files/media/pdfs/About_VIA/our-company/annual-reports/2013/VIA_Rapport_annuel_EN_FINAL.pdf).  The [2014 Q1 report](http://www.viarail.ca/sites/all/files/media/pdfs/About_VIA/our-company/quartely-reports/2013/RT_Q1_en_v14.pdf) makes mention that *On-Time performance (...) on the Canadian (...) plummeted to 25%*.

Is there any location where on-time performance per route is publicly available?

Comment: just went hunting for this again, stumbled on the same [overall reports for 2013](http://www.viarail.ca/2013annualreport/docs/via-annual-report-2013.pdf) :/ Will keep trying.

Comment: It mentions total ontime performance was 82% for the year, and shows the prior 3 years. Not per route tho :/

Comment: I too can not locate official time performance statistics. I have been informed by experienced travel guides that the Via Rail Vancouver to Toronto rarely arrives Toronto Union before 5 PM. The official posted time of arrival is 9:00 AM. I was traveling with fourteen others in my group and we arrived fourteen ( 14) hours late. The group believed it an important route that should be more carefully scheduled. Better to publish the time the train arrives at most often than continue to publish an unattainable time. We all lost an entire day of sight seeing in Toronto (dollars to be spent).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I contacted [Via Rail's social media account](https://twitter.com/marksmayo/status/532865627522732032), and they had [this to say](https://twitter.com/VIA_Rail/status/532870035719860224):

> Hi Mark: No comprehensive report, but requests accepted/considered at
>   Customer_Relations@viarail.ca or media@viarail.ca. ^MA

So it seems like you're out of luck in terms of published reports, but you can possibly get a per-route one if you contact their customer relations email address.

Answer (score 4):

These days, you can find per-route stats at [www.trainstats.ca](http://www.trainstats.ca/). (This site did not exist yet when the question was asked, I believe.)